# How to let callee know who is the caller

Tags: javascript

I have three functions a,b and c. function b and c both call function a.
is it possible to add some code in function a which will get info on which function is the caller?

```
function a()
{
   alert ("Hello");
}

function b()
{
    a();
}

function c()
{
    b();
}
```

Comment: Just pass a parameter to `a`?

Comment: what is your use case ?

Comment: Actually function `c` calls `b`.